# Implementation event-based game server architecture

Tags: design, design-patterns, server

I'm trying to develop a game server in [Netty](https://netty.io/) using an event-based approach where incoming events are dispatched to the correct game rooms, but I'm having some trouble with managing my world state. My game is a small action top down fighter with 20 people in a single roon.

`[0, 7, 8, 4, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111]`

- The first 2 bytes are the length
- The third byte is the event type
- The other bytes are the payload.

The incoming packets are decoded using my `EventDecoder`, then passed to my `GameServerHandler` which dispatches the events using an RxJava eventbus implementation where my gameroom/sessions are listening for.

`EventDecoder`

```
//Read the command
int type = msg.readUnsignedByte(); //The event type (e.g 8 = Change position)

ByteBuf buffer = msg.readBytes(msg.readableBytes());
out.add(new Event(type, buffer));
```

My `World` class receives the incoming events, put them in a `Queue` and gets handled on my server game loop every tick.

```
@Override
public void input(@NotNull Event event) {
    Log.d("Processing event " + event.getType().value + " from client");

    switch (event.getType()) {
        case UPDATE_POSITION:
            updatePosition(event);
            break;
    }

}

private void updatePosition(@NotNull Event event) {
    if (event.getSession() instanceof PlayerSession) {
        User user = ((PlayerSession) event.getSession()).getUser();
        // Find the user in the user list
        // Update user position based on event buffer
        // Notify client in onUpdate game loop

    }
}
```

I think the code here will get really bloated and I'd need to do a lot of checks

My question is if there are any best practices for handling these events. Would I need different subclasses for the event classes and register them while decoding (e.g `UpdatePositionEvent`)?

Comment: Question re. best practices are usually too opinionated for SE. Your idea is a good thing, do it. Whether that will prevent complicated checks depends much more on the semantics of your events rather than the form in which they appear.

Comment: My question is maybe a bit malformed and I'm rather looking on how other people would implement such state management based on events. Would you create more specific event classes on event creation and/of using a strategy pattern to hide the implementation details in the event subclasses.

Comment: Modelling your events independently from their wire format (i.e. creating a class per event and hiding as much event-related stuff in these classes) cannot possibly hurt your code. I'd 100% do it. But to help with anything beyond that we need to know more about the semantics of your events.